# Implementing 'insert' function for binary tree in C

Tags: c, tree, insert, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement the usual 'insert' function for binary tree in C, and I can't figure out where my code is wrong (it is wrong, for sure, though, since it doesn't work...).

Can someone help me out figuring out what I did wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int data;
} node;

void insert (node *root, int n);
void print (node *root);

int main(void){

    node *root = malloc(sizeof(node));
    root->left = root->right = NULL; 
    root->data = 50;

    insert (root, 1);
}


void insert (node *root, int n){

    node *cursor = root;

    while (cursor != NULL){

        if (n <= cursor->data){
            cursor = cursor->left;
            printf("left\n");
        }

        else if (cursor->data < n){
            cursor = cursor->right;
            printf("right\n");
        }

        else {
            printf("Invalid data in the tree.\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    cursor = malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("%p\n", root->left);
    cursor->data = n;
    cursor->left = NULL;
    cursor->right = NULL;

}

void print (node* root){

    if (root == NULL){
        return;
    }

    print(root->left);
    printf("%i ", root->data);
    print(root->right);

}
```

Comment: oh, by the way there are some printf's that I added in the function, trying to debug.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You say "it doesn't work", can you please tell us *how* it doesn't work? Does you get compilation errors (or warnings)? Does it crash runtime? Is the behavior or output unexpected? Have you tried running or stepping in a debugger? In the future please include all such details.

Comment: However in your case it's quite easy to see what's wrong, you don't actually *insert* new nodes in the tree anywhere. You just allocate a new node, but nowhere do you actually add it to the tree.

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work since when I print the tree out, I don't get the value that I inserted -- and I know the print function is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
typedef struct node {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int data;
} node;
    
void insert (node *root, int n);
void print (node *root);
    
int main(void){
    node *root = malloc(sizeof(node));
    root->left = root->right = NULL; 
    root->data = 50;
        
    insert (root, 1);
}
    
void insert (node *root, int n){
    node *cursor = root;
    
    while (cursor != NULL){
        if (n <= cursor->data){
            cursor = cursor->left;
            printf("left\n");
        }else if (cursor->data < n){
            cursor = cursor->right;
            printf("right\n");
        }else {
                printf("Invalid data in the tree.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
        
    cursor = malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("%p\n", root->left);
    cursor->data = n;
    cursor->left = NULL;
    cursor->right = NULL;
}

void print (node* root){
        if (root == NULL){
            return;
        }
    
        print(root->left);
        printf("%i ", root->data);
        print(root->right);
}
```

Lets say you want to add 1 to the tree below

```
  5
 / \
2   8
```

Your code has a cursor pointer.

That cursor pointer points to 5 then 2 and then NULL.

When it reaches NULL you allocate new memory and your cursor points to that new memory.

That's it. You haven't made what you wanted to.

The cursor pointer is not a part of the tree. It's just a variable you use to access the nodes of your tree.

Now the node *left and node *right are parts of your tree and these are the nodes you must allocate memory to.

One solution to your problem is the code below:

```
void insert (node **root, int n){
    node *cursor = *root;

    while (cursor != NULL){
        if (n <= cursor->data){
            cursor = *(root=&cursor->left);
            printf("left\n");
        }else if (cursor->data < n){
            cursor = *(root=&cursor->right);
            printf("right\n");
        }else {
            printf("Invalid data in the tree.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
   
    *root = malloc(sizeof(node));
    cursor=*root;

    cursor->data = n;
    cursor->left = NULL;
    cursor->right = NULL;
}

int main(void){
    node *root = NULL; 
    
    insert (&root, 1);
}
```

Further Improve:

```
void insert (node **root, int n){
    node *cursor = *root;

    while (cursor != NULL) cursor=*(root=(n<cursor->data)?&cursor->left:&cursor->right);
        
    cursor=*root=malloc(sizeof(node));

    cursor->data = n;
    cursor->left = NULL;
    cursor->right = NULL;
}

int main(void){
    node *root = NULL; 
    
    insert (&root, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are allocating to `cursor` and `cursor->left` or `cursor->right` is unallocated.
Make sure newly allocated node is pointed by `cursor->left` or `cursor->right`.

```
void insert (node *root, int n){

    node *cursor = root;

    while (cursor != NULL){

        if (n <= cursor->data){  /* Change 1 follows */
            printf("left\n");
            if(cursor->left == NULL) {
            cursor->left = malloc(sizeof(node));
            cursor = cursor->left;
            break;
           }
        }

        else if (cursor->data < n){
            printf("right\n");
            if(cursor->right == NULL) {  /* Change 2 follows */
              cursor->right = malloc(sizeof(node));
              cursor = cursor->right;
              break;
            }
        }

        else {
            printf("Invalid data in the tree.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    /* Change 3 : 1 line deleted */
    printf("%p\n", root->left); /* Why? */
    cursor->data = n;
    cursor->left = NULL;
    cursor->right = NULL;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a reference to the previous `cursor`. You need to find the place where `cursor->data` is null; but if you are looking to find where `cursor` itself is null, it doesn't do anything for you, since `cursor` is not a reference to the previous `cursor->data`, but a copy: when you change `cursor`, nothing in your structure changes.